# When do custom cells from nib release

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

We dont allocate the nib based view so there seems no point in releasing them as we get the view from bundle.I have a scenario where i have custom cells made from nib.Even when i release the tableview containing the UITableView cell the cell object stays in the memory.I havent retained it anywhere else.I would appreciate any answers thanks

Comment: The cells are put in a queue for reuse. You should first try to call your tableViews DequeueReusableCell - use a specific name for specific cell types.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the object from the bundle it assigns it to an IBOutlet instance variable.  You need to release the instance in dealloc in the usual way.  This is how I do it,

```
in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //get a new cell instance from the xib
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ASEventTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
  //get the object from the outlet
  cell = [self eventsTableViewCell];

The in viewDidUnload,
self.eventsTableViewCell=nil;

And dealloc
[eventsTableViewCell release];
```

Comment: I dont think we need to release it if the property for the instance variable is not retained.In my case this causes a crash as logically i am trying to release some autorelease object.But if i dont the autorelease pool seems to forget if some thing was added to it.anyways thanks for the reply